# Terminal highlighting and auto complete

Tags: bash, postgresql, unix, terminal

Do you know some plugin for highlighting and autocomplete in postgreSQL terminal?

Comment: `psql` does auto completion by default.

Comment: yes but not convenient. I want to use tools like zsh, pry (for Rails) for database.

Comment: *not convenient*, a very precise definition of what you want...

Answer (score 1):

[pgcli](https://github.com/amjith/pgcli) - Postgres CLI with autocompletion and syntax highlighting

Installation

```
$ pip install pgcli
```

Usage

```
$ pgcli [database_name]
```